# How do I tell which button called another view in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

[image]

I want to know which button called the second view which displays a list of the type of items. The tableViewCell contains an array of all the items. For example, if the user taps on burgers he gets a list of all the burger items. I have connected each button to the second view individually but it seems like there has to be a better way like connecting it to the touchButton method that all buttons are connected to but I'm not sure how to do this. Also, should the array of items be in tableViewController or is tableViewCell fine?

Comment: use didSelectRowAt method for your tableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of giving each button segue for same view, i recommend you to use only one segue.

One approach is to simply use a indicator int or string depending upon your logic in items table view and assign it accordingly in prepare for segue method by getting destinationVC. And handle the indicator on list items view on loading. (in this approach you have only one segue and you will be able to perform the work).

As far as table view approach is concerned. use tableview for list of items and use tableViewCell for individual items.

Comment: How do I use a single segue?

Comment: define one segues with identifier. 
in prepare for segue method use if segue.identifier == "you_segues_id" { 
}
then assign the var in new view controller. let me give you a code example.

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "your_segue_id" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
            vc.type = "your_pressed_button_string"
        }
    }

Comment: its one of approach you can use other as well

Answer (score 0):

**In theory :**

If you are moving onto the next `ViewController` from *current* , you can create a variable inside the next *View Controller* and while moving from current VC to next, you can fetch the name of the *Button* inside the `@IBAction` method and create instance of next VC and access that *variable* (created earlier) and assign the name of that button to that *variable*

**Code :**

```
class CurrentViewController: UIViewController {

  // Your other code goes here

  @IBAction func actionButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

     // Here we fetch the name of the button tapped
     let nameOfButtonTapped = sender.titleLabel!.text

     // Here we create instance of NextViewController
     let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "#yourNextVCIdentifierHere") as! NextViewController

     // Here we assign the name of the button tapped to the variable of NextViewController so we can access it there
     nextVC.buttonNameThatWasClicked = nameOfButtonTapped

     self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
}

class NextViewController: UIViewController {

  var buttonNameThatWasClicked: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   print(buttonNameThatWasClicked!)

  }

}
```

Here, we can connect *All the Buttons to a single `@IBAction` by control-dragging all the buttons to the name of the @IBAction method*

Comment: I got this warning:  Unsupported Configuration: “Items Table View Controller“ is unreachable because it has no entry points, and no identifier for runtime access via -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]. Plus its not connected to the navigation bar

Comment: Did you gave an **identifier** to the `ItemsTableViewController` via storyboard ? I believe you have not provided any _identifier_ , that's why you are getting this warning